# webpack/babel/es6 import issue - (0 , _whatwgFetch2.default) is not a function

Tags: npm, webpack, fetch, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am importing `whatwg-fetch`(https://github.com/github/fetch) into my app

```
import fetch from 'whatwg-fetch';
```

For local development I use `webpack-dev-server`. I got this error message:

```
 test.js?ba55:67 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _whatwgFetch.fetch) is not a function
```

It is fired from this line:

```
fetch('/api/mydata', opts)
```

Why the import failed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`whatwg-fetch` is actually a polyfill

I only need to import it this way:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

Comment: Sometimes when I answer my own questions I wonder "will this even help anyone?"  Well just so you know, posting your own answer just helped me figure out a problem that only had four Google results (this one and three useless ones).  Thanks!